# An entire function of exponential type on nonparallel lines.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function of exponential type, i.e., there exist constants $A$ and $B$ such that
\begin{equation*}
|f(z)| \le A e^{B|z|}
\end{equation*} for all complex $z$. Prove that if $f$ is bounded on two nonparallel lines, then it  must be a constant. I think it may be related to the Paley and Wiener Theorem, but I have no idea how anyway. Can anyone help?

Comment: See [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle for a sector in the complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragmén–Lindelöf_principle#Phragmén–Lindelöf_principle_for_a_sector_in_the_complex_plane)

Comment: @Martin R, Oh! I got the points. Thanks a lot!